# Passing DIV through $data variable, but with an Echo Statement in String

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Confused by the title? hehe. Not sure how to explain this one, but I think my snippet of code should explain things a little easier.

This is what I'm trying to pass through the `$data` variable. `div` is displayed as it should be, but the `echo` statement inside (which I need) is NOT displayed.

Where am I messing up?

`$data['packagename'] = '<div class="somedoodoo"> echo $row->subscription </div>';`

Comment: While this is the Internet, SO generally tends more professional than most other social-type sites; the language is really unnecessary.

Comment: Lighten up mate...yeah? Thanks General for keeping the internet safe! Salute! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use string concatenation:

```
$data['packagename'] = '<div class="something">' . $row->subscription . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't execute code inside a string like that, plus, it's the wrong quotes:

```
$data['packagename'] = <<<EOL
<div class="somedoodoo">{$row->subscription}</div>
EOL;
```

relevant docs on heredocs: http://php.net/heredoc

Comment: EOL?? Haven't seem this or the brackets in CI yet... interesting. Thanks man. Reading doc now. :)